# Does anybody knows if API openshift-restclient-java can restart a POD

Tags: openshift

I am trying programmatically to restart a POD in openshift? I can connect and query using this client API [openshift-restclient-java](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-restclient-java/)

If so is there any sample code or link to one that can be provided?

Comment: The REST API endpoints ``/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods`` allows you to query pods. Using the ``DELETE`` HTTP verb, you should also be able to delete a pod, which would have the effect of restarting it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this method. I did not get a chance to try but it looks like it might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this method to restart the pod. I am posting this answer in case somebody have the same task.

```
def restartPod(podName: String, nameSpace: String): Boolean =  {

val serviceList: Seq[IResource] = openshiftClient.list[IResource](ResourceKind.DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG, nameSpace).filter(service => service.getName.startsWith(podName)).toList
serviceList match {
  case service :: _ => {
    scaleTo(service, 0) match {
      case None => println(s"Pod ${podName} successfully stopped.")
      case Some(ex) => {
        println(s"Error stopping pod ${podName} reason: ${ex.getMessage}")
      }
    }
    scaleTo(service, 1) match {
      case None => {
        val message = s"Pod ${podName} successfully started."
        println(message)
        (true)
      }
      case Some(ex) => {
        val message = s"Error starting pod ${podName} reason: ${ex.getMessage}"
        logger.error(message)
        (false)
      }
    }
  }
  case _ => {
    val message = s"Pod ${podName} could not be restarted because it was not found with that name."
    logger.error(message)
    (false)
  }
}
}
```

You would need the following library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>openshift-restclient-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am currently playing around the first time with opensfhit-restclient-java and have achieved your task by doing as the following snippet illustrates.

**What does the code do:**

1. Scale the service instance to 0
2. Wait until the pod is really gone
3. Scale the service instance back to 1
4. Wait until the service instance is really up
5. Whatever needs to be done, when the service instance is up

**Implementation:**

```
private static boolean scaleDeployment(final IClient client,
                                           final String dcName,
                                           final String namespace,
                                           final int scale) {
        DeploymentConfig dc = client.get(ResourceKind.DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG, dcName, namespace);
        boolean result = false;
        if (dc != null) {
            dc.setDesiredReplicaCount(scale);
            client.update(dc);
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static boolean waitForPodToDisappear(final IClient client,
                                                 final String namespace,
                                                 final Map<String, String> labels,
                                                 final int maxTries,
                                                 final int waitInMillis) {
        int tries = 0;
        List<Pod> pods = client.list(ResourceKind.POD, namespace, labels);
        while (!pods.isEmpty() && tries < maxTries) {
            pods = client.list(ResourceKind.POD, namespace, labels);
            if (!pods.isEmpty()) {
                tries += 1;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(waitInMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return pods.isEmpty();
    }

    private static boolean isPodReady(final Pod pod) {
        final List<ModelNode> conditions = pod.getNode()
                                              .get("status")
                                              .get("conditions")
                                              .asList();
        return conditions.stream()
                         .filter(node -> (node.get("type").asString().contains("Ready")))
                         .filter(node -> node.get("status").asString().contains("True"))
                         .count() == 1;
    }

    private static boolean waitForPodToBecomeReady(final IClient client,
                                                   final String namespace,
                                                   final Map<String, String> labels,
                                                   final int maxTries,
                                                   final int waitInMillis) {
        int tries = 0;
        boolean result = false;
        while (!result && tries < maxTries) {
            final List<Pod> pods = client.list(ResourceKind.POD, namespace, labels);
            if (pods.size() == 1) {
                result = isPodReady(pods.get(0));
            }
            if (!result) {
                tries += 1;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(waitInMillis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void main(String args[]) {
        IClient client = new ClientBuilder().toCluster("https://127.0.0.1:8443")
                                            .withConnectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                            .withUserName("developer")
                                            .withPassword("developer")
                                            .build();
        boolean result = false;
        // Stop service instance
        scaleDeployment(client, "myservice-dc", "namespace", 0);
        // Wait until service Pod is gone
        result = waitForPodToDisappear(client, "namespace", new HashMap<String, String>() {{
            put("name", "myservice-dc-label");
        }}, 100, 1000);
        if(result) {
          // Start backup service instance
          scaleDeployment(client, "myservice-dc", "namespace", 1);
          result = waitForPodToBecomeReady(client, "namespace", new HashMap<String, String>() {{
              put("name", "myservice-dc-label");
          }}, 100, 1000);
          if(result) {
            // Do stuff, which requires the pod to be ready
          }
        }
    }
```

As I already wrote, theses are my fist steps with the openshift-restclient-java.

You need the following dependency for oc 3.6+

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.openshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>openshift-restclient-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```